# Fitting element into table cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, css-tables

I am trying to fit a canvas element into a table cell with no padding at all, i.e. I want no margins between my canvas and top/bottom of the cell. Therefore, I define row height as 20px and canvas height as 20px. I also use padding:0px styling. However, I get no padding only from top and left and I still do get padding at the bottom. In fact, it looks like the table cell gets taller in order to accommodate for the undesired margin. How can I resolve it?

Also, what is the difference between defining canvas width and height in HTML and CSS? Will one override the other?

Below is my HTML code.
Thanks.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>experiment</title>
<body>

<script>
  $(function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('my_canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');    
      ctx.fillRect(0,0,20,20);  
      $("#my_table > tbody > tr:eq(0) > td:eq(0)").append($("#my_canvas"));
  })

</script>
</head>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">

    .my_cell {height:20px; width:100px; padding:0}
    .my_canvas {height:20px; width:20px}
</style>

<table id="my_table" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpinserting="0">
<tbody>
    <tr><td class="my_cell"></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<canvas id="my_canvas" class="my_canvas" width="20" height="20"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Generally the `width` and `height` HTML attributes are deprecated in HTML5, I think even earlier. In short, I think it was simply because styling is the job of CSS. However, due to backwards compatibility which is one of the main goals of HTML5, you can still use them... They will be overridden by CSS if I am not mistaking.

Comment: @Derija93: I have tried to remove the HTML width/height and it stopped working. So it looks like they are needed. Still not clear what CSS does to the canvas.

Comment: Well that is generally spoken. Have a look at the w3 schools' [web reference on the `canvas` element](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_canvas.asp). Apparently particularly those two attributes are needed for your canvas element to know its viewport width and height. I guess it needs those to be specified in HTML because it otherwise has no means to access the dimensions set in CSS. Using a debugger and when those two attributes are removed, the HTML element itself is still 20x20 while the black rect drawn is reduced to a minimum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the following to the canvas's style:

```
display : block;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/S7YJu/

You can see why if you look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/S7YJu/1/ - by default the canvas displays `inline` which means it lines up in a way that leaves space for the bottom of letters like "y" or "p" to hang beneath...

Answer (score 0):

Despite your question has been  already answered i would like to point the following.

Canvas element are treated very like inline elements despite the seem to be [block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements), similar to how [an image element is treated](http://sixrevisions.com/html/canvas-element/). To fix your problem you have to set the style rule `display` to `block` for canvas.

with the best of intentions i would like to give you some advice :

1 You omitted th opening body tag.

2 Is recomended to put script tags at bottom.

4 Use divs instead of table elements when possible.

5 You don't always use Jquery selectors...

i.e.

```
document.getElementById('my_canvas');
```

Copy ->

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
  .my_cell {width:100px; }
  .my_canvas {display: block;height:20px; width:20px; background-color: red}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="my_table" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpinserting="0" cellpadding="0">
     <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td class="my_cell"></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".my_cell").html('<canvas class="my_canvas" width="20" height="20"></canvas>');
            });

       var canvas = $('.my_canvas');
       var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');    
       ctx.fillRect(0,0,0,20,20);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```